# Can decimal values slow a jquery/css animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm having a huge flow problem with an animation in mobile android devices. The animation is built in JS   with jquery velocity plugin which creates css transitions. Some of the values for these transitions are calculated width the viewport size so in some cases the values give decimals.

The animation works fine in desktops and iOS but in Android it chops. I've tried the translateZ=0 solution but it doesn't solve the problem. And I'm trying to optimize the script all I can.

Do you think that decimals could slow a transition calculation by the Android GPU?

A code example of what I'm doing:

```
$('.set1').velocity({ 
                translateX:-((set1Wi*1.5+winWi)),
                translateY:-100,
                translateZ:0, 
                scale:(2,2)},{
                duration: 2000,
                delay:500,
                easing:'linear',

            })
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show a small example that triggers this behavior?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel sorry, I've just added a sample. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you for the example. Looking quickly, I can see that you are using a plugin. Can you provide a link to the website? It's possible that the plugin relies on jQuery's implementation for animations, which is CPU-based.

Comment: `Do you think that decimals could slow a transition calculation by the Android GPU?` If you parse it to integer, does animation speed is better? Seems quite easy to check it

Comment: Thanks! The plugin is velocity http://julian.com/research/velocity/

Comment: @A.Wolff I've already done with Math.round. But in the translate execution it is using decimals. Thanks!

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Does not the "translateZ" forcing the GPU to handle the animation? --> I've just realize that it doesn't, because velocity doesn't apply transformations with 0 value

Comment: @nach Not sure what you have tried, but i meant: `translateX:-parseInt((set1Wi*1.5+winWi), 10),` Test it and see if your issue comes from decimals or not. (here radix seems useless but that's just a good habit)

Comment: @nach It depends: if the library relies on CSS3, it will. Otherwise, it won't have any effect.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel its a re-implementation of jQuery's animate. In the docs it says its faster than css libraries but it creates css transforms effects so it should rely on css, doesn't it?

Comment: @nach I have been reading the source code and it seems to me that the animations are handled using javascript. Using the `translateZ` trick won't work. Try removing the `easing` and increasing the duration a little (instead of 2000, you can try 2100). Ultimately, try to remove the `translate` and `scale` and replace with "similar" values.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel thanks! It's weird because it overwrites any trassform given before with css. I'll try your advice thanks! Right now I'm trying a solution using css transition. I've just read it can trigger the GPU usage too. But the results are frutrating, every thing that improves in Android with transition, gets worst in iOS

Comment: @nach For 2D transitions, I don't think you will need the GPU. I dont know anything about the HTML structure that you are using and the number of child elements and the CSS applied to them. This is nowhere a scientific review or something on those lines, but it's just my opinion and what I should do: I would try to reduce the css applied to the elements as well as the number of elements present. Avoiding pseudo-elements might help a little. Using less css hacks (floats and the clearfix hack) and applying the transition to only a single property (like opacity or width) can improve things a bit.